# Using Action Class, After ClickAndHold, how can I go to two step bottom menu option and click?

Tags: java, selenium

{ actions.clickAndHold(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN)
        .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform(); }

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmTK1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something like this? Obviously the selectors I used can be improved. I am not sure why we are clicking and holding and then pressing keys down. When we do this manually, that is not the action that we are taking. We basically move to the Rankings menu, then move to the womens link, then click if needed.

```
        driver.get("https://www.cricbuzz.com");
        WebElement rankingMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Rankings')]"));
        WebElement womensSelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='ICC Rankings Women']"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(rankingMenu).moveToElement(womensSelect).click().build().perform();
```